# AndEngine Scene Transitions

Tags: android, andengine, scene

I've asked this on official AndEngine forums, but might as well post it here.

Is there any way to add cool transitions when switching scenes? I'm using the Scene / Resource Manager to create and destroy scenes and I would like to add some transitions in-between, similar to overridePendingTransition() of regular Android's Activity.

I've tried registering MoveModifier to my scene, but either the background doesn't move or I get black screen as scene moves.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `Scene` transitions like `Activities` transitions but you can add a splash/loading dialogue (full screen if you want so) with animations until your "next scene" resources are loaded, that's the best scenario I could manage so far:

[Progress bar while loading Textures in AndEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937303/progress-bar-while-loading-textures-in-andengine/24958345#24958345)

Other solution would be having a `Scene` with 2 or more `Entities` (your menus let's say) and animate the transition between this `Entities` with `Entity Modifiers`. Not the best solution but if your menus are simple "options menus" this could be a considerable solution.